# Handling errors with jQuery $.getScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a function that automatically loads .js files for modules with jQuery .getScript() function. The problem is that if the loaded script has any errors in it I cannot find a way to display the error line from the file loaded. I found a way to display the error type and error message but not the error line.

```
jQuery.getScript(main.constants.BASEURL + main.modules[activeModule].path + 'js/functions.js')
    .done(function() {                      
        Module.init();                      
    })
    .fail(function(jqxhr, settings, exception) {                            
        errorObj = {};
        if (arguments[0].readyState == 0) {
            errorObj.message = 'Failed to load script!';
            //script failed to load
        }
        else {
            errorObj.type = arguments[1];
            errorObj.message = arguments[2]['message'];
            errorObj.lineNo = ??; //This is what I need to find
            //script loaded but failed to parse                         
        }
        console.log(errorObj);                                      
    });
```

Comment: Why can't you just print all of the arguments and look for the line number? If it's not there, then it's going to be difficult to obtain.

Comment: It's not there, I've tried this already

Comment: For development/testing, include the files explicitly and save the dynamic loading for later. Otherwise get a hold of the free version of Visual Studio, which should breakpoint on any error in any loaded file.

Comment: Sorry, may I know where did the argument array come from?

Comment: The question is over 6y old... Even if I try, I can't remember

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamiclly add a new script tag to head you will see line numbers,  use scripts element onload to init the module

Comment: That is an alternative, but it's not the solution to the request I had. If I will not find any solution for $.getScript() I will switch to that...